# What does "$" in observable property mean?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm a newbie angular. I have a code example, but the creator does not explain to me the "$" what that mean, Can anyone tell me what `blog$` and `onDestroy$` here means? Or is that just how he named it?
Thanks you!

blog-details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { BlogService } from '../../services/blog.service';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { BlogItem } from '../../models/blog-item.model';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-detail',
  templateUrl: './blog-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog-detail.component.scss']
})
export class BlogDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  blog$: Observable<BlogItem>;
  private onDestroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private readonly blogService: BlogService, private readonly route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)).subscribe((params: any) => {
      const { id } = params;
      this.blog$ = this.blogService.getBlogDetail(id);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.onDestroy$.next(true);
    this.onDestroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

blog-detail.component.html

```
<p>blog-detail works!</p>
<div class="blog-detail" *ngIf="blog$ | async as blogDetail; else loading;">
    <div class="blog-detail-title">{{ blogDetail?.title }}</div>
    <div class="blog-detail-content">
      Content:
      <span>{{ blogDetail?.body }}</span>
    </div>
    <div>userId: {{ blogDetail?.userId }}</div>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
  Loading...
</ng-template>
```

Comment: it's just how he named it, $ at the end of the variable is just a way to differ observable variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` is a naming convention for observables and subjects. It is a way to mark that the variable is a "stream" rather than a plain object. It is an indicator that you can subscribe, pipe, and use rxjs operators with the variable. In Angular, it helps you remember that you can use the async pipe in the html.